# Print all even numbers in a list until a given number

Tags: python

I am just beginning to dabble in Python, and have started to go through the chapters on learnpython.org. In the 'Loops' chapter, I have solved the challenge with the following code. However I am not sure it is the most efficient. It certainly doesn't seem to be as I have to define the "number to not go beyond" twice. In this (I'm guessing) easy problem, DRY should be possible to adhere to, right?

The [exercise](http://www.learnpython.org/page/Loops) is

> Loop through and print out all even numbers from the numbers list in
>   the same order they are received. Don't print any numbers that come
>   after 237 in the sequence.

My code:

```
numbers = [ 951, 402, 984, 651, 360, 69, 408, 319, 601, 485, 980, 507, 725, 547, 544, 615, 83, 165, 141, 501, 263, 617, 865, 575, 219, 390, 984, 592, 236, 105, 942, 941, 386, 462, 47, 418, 907, 344, 236, 375, 823, 566, 597, 978, 328, 615, 953, 345, 399, 162, 758, 219, 918, 237, 412, 566, 826, 248, 866, 950, 626, 949, 687, 217, 815, 67, 104, 58, 512, 24, 892, 894, 767, 553, 81, 379, 843, 831, 445, 742, 717, 958, 609, 842, 451, 688, 753, 854, 685, 93, 857, 440, 380, 126, 721, 328, 753, 470, 743, 527 ]

# My Solution
for x in numbers:
  if x != 237:
    if x % 2 == 0:
      print x
  if x == 237:
    break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what `else` and `elif` are for:

```
for x in numbers:
  if x == 237:
    break
  elif x % 2 == 0:
    print x
```

Comment: It's a pathetic speed improvement but testing for evenness before equality is probably going to be quicker as a number is more likely to be even than equal to 237 and 237 isn't even.

Comment: Well, that makes so much sense... Not really sure why I went and overcomplicated things... :) Thx

Comment: Actually, neither else nor elif are essential in your example. The 4th line could be just `if x%2==0`.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is using `itertools` which always comes in useful some way or another:

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile, ifilter
>>> not_237 = takewhile(lambda L: L != 237, numbers)
>>> is_even = ifilter(lambda L: L % 2 == 0, not_237)
>>> list(is_even)
[402, 984, 360, 408, 980, 544, 390, 984, 592, 236, 942, 386, 462, 418, 344, 236, 566, 978, 328, 162, 758, 918]
```

So we create a lazy iterator that stops at 237, then take from that even numbers

Comment: I'm sure that's really neat, but did you read the part about "simple examples"? :)

Comment: @PatrikAlienus Well - I think it's simpler and clearer than looping :)

Comment: Okay I guess it's an addition to the collective knowledge, but I don't understand more than 10 % of that :)

Answer (score 1):

This is also possible:

```
try:
    i = numbers.index(237)
except:
    i = len(numbers)
for n in numbers[:i]:
    if not n%2:
       print n
```

Comment: Yes, but you have to handle an exception then.

Comment: @thg435, thanks for reminding me to that issue - I,ve fixed it -- but it looks horrible and has severable performance flaws -- I better delete this answer;)

Comment: I think the answer is quite helpful in this form.

Comment: This is helpful to me, at least. I'm getting to see that there are indeed maaaany ways of achieving the same goal. Question is, how does one benchmark to see which is the most efficient? Human readability is usually not a good measuring stick :)

Answer (score 0):

Im just going throug this exercise in my "learning the basis thing" and i came out with a similar but somehow worse solution, patrik :(

`x = 0
for loop in numbers:
    if (numbers[x]) % 2 ==0:
        print (numbers[x])
        x = x+1

    if (numbers[x]) ==237:
        break

    else:
        x =x+1
        continue`

Comment: The asker is asking for a more efficient way of solving the problem. You state that your solution is "somewhat worse". May I suggest that you either update your answer with more efficient code or delete this answer entirely.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that using list comprehension

The solution would be like this:

```
numbers = [x for ind,x in enumerate(numbers) if x % 2== 0 and numbers[ind+1]!=237 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

> 3 if's and done :)

```
    if x % 2 == 0:
        print x
    if x == 237:
        break
    if x % 2 != 0: 
        continue
```

Output

```
402
984
360
408
980
544
390
984
592
236
942
386
462
418
344
236
566
978
328
162
758
918
```