# Print numbers, don't understand the error

Tags: python, python-3.x

My (simple) code gives an error at the last line. What am I doing wrong?

The question:

> Loop through and print out all even numbers from the numbers list in the same order they are received. Don't print any numbers that come after 237 in the sequence.

What am I doing wrong?

```
numbers = [951, 402, 984, 651, 360, 69, 408, 319, 601, 485, 980, 507, 725, 547, 544, 
615, 83, 165, 141, 501, 263, 617, 865, 575, 219, 390, 984, 592, 236, 105, 942, 941, 
386, 462, 47, 418, 907, 344, 236, 375, 823, 566, 597, 978, 328, 615, 953, 345, 
399, 162, 758, 219, 918, 237, 412, 566, 826, 248, 866, 950, 626, 949, 687, 217, 
815, 67, 104, 58, 512, 24, 892, 894, 767, 553, 81, 379, 843, 831, 445, 742, 717, 
958, 609, 842, 451, 688, 753, 854, 685, 93, 857, 440, 380, 126, 721, 328, 753, 470, 
743, 527]
# your code goes here
for number in numbers:
    if number <= 237 and number % 2 == 0:
        continue
        print numbers
```

Comment: Is your indentation correct?  You'll never hit the `print` statement if the indentation you have here is what you have in your actual code.

Comment: If you are a beginner, once this works, try solving this problem using filter function.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14537063/print-all-even-numbers-in-a-list-until-a-given-number/

Answer (score 2):

You need to lose the `continue`, it'll move the loop to the next iteration instead. I think you were looking for `break` (when you find `237`).

Just print `number`, but do make `print()` a function for Python 3.

```
for number in numbers:
    if number == 237:
        break
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print(number)
```

Comment: His numbers are not sorted. `break` is unnecessary, unless input is ASC sorted

Comment: @rosipov: *Because* the numbers are not sorted, you need a `break`. So, print all even numbers, but stop once you come across 237 in the sequence.

Comment: Oh. Misread the question. My bad.